# Implementation of Host Resource MIB in linux OS

Tags: linux, snmp, mib

While executing below snmpwalk command

snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost host

I am getting only this as output for my linux system

HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 = STRING: 2012-8-16,10:43:20.0,-5:30
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)

Why I am not getting other HOST-RESOURCE MIBs...How can I get all of  those MIBs??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use net-snmp as the agent?

I tested this with NET-SNMP version: 5.7.1 and it works fine.

Comment: I got it.....actually I simply have to cnfigured on snmpd.conf file...& now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Add your HOST-RESOURCES MIB file to the directory where all your other MIB files exist. You can find this directory in the snmpd.conf file as
**mibdirs /usr/share/snmp/mibs/**. Also, mention the MIB files to be used in the snmpd.conf file mentioned as **mibs THALES-SMI:THALES-ECOS2-MIB**